# Is it possible to detect within a .Net program that it is being stopped/stepped through in the debugger?

Tags: .net, debugging, timeout

This is to address an issue that bothers my debugging at times. The program I'm working on detects user inactivity in the UI (mouse + keyboard) and time-outs if the user has no activity over a configurable time span.  The problem I'm having is that the user inactivity is counted even if I'm debugging the program and I would like to have the ability to substract the time I spend in the debugger from the user inactivity time, so the program does not time out while I am debugging it.

Comment: Use Debugger.IsAttached.  It tells you that a time-out *could* trigger.  Breaks are otherwise unobservable from the program.

Answer (score 1):

You could just disable the timeout code in the `DEBUG` builds of your application.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. The problem is that occasionally I need to debug behavior that happens after a timeout occurred, the condition is cleared and I'm debugging in the middle of the next [supposed] user activity period.

I guess that a workaround will be to have a DEBUG-only bool member that I can set to false in the debugger after the first inactivity timeout occurs and will prevent the next user inactivity timeout to fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could use compiler directives.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: Please don't post version-specific links unless the question is version-specific.